# Force discovery of SAS device

Tags: 18.04, devices, sasl, scsi

I have a tape drive attach to an SAS card on my Ubuntu 18.04 box. If I power cycle the drive with the computer running `/dev/nst0` disappears and does not come back without a reboot (which is a non-trivial thing to do).

Is there a way to force re-discovery of the tape drive?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the command below to force re-detection of disks. I have seen the command cause issues with externally-mounted LUKS partitions, so if you have any of those, I would suggest dismounting them before trying this command

```
sudo partprobe
```